# Add buttons dynamically which also add textboxes dynamically AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, data-binding, dynamic-html

I have this JSFiddle code :

http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/285/

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choicesA">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
         <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
      <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>


   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choicesA }} <br/>
      {{ choicesB }}
   </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choicesA = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];

  $scope.choicesB = [];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choicesA.length+1;
    $scope.choicesA.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choicesA.length-1;
    $scope.choicesA.splice(lastItem);
  };

});
```

As you can see, I have a function `addNewChoice()` which adds objects to the array `choicesA`, and then Textboxes get added based on objects number on the `choicesA` array.

I need to add textboxes to the first `fieldset` only when I click on the `Add fields` button on the first `fieldset`, and the data that I write on those generated textboxes is binded and added to seperate objects to the `choicesB` array. and the same for all the other `Add fields` buttons (so each `Add field` button can only add textboxes to its own `fieldset` tag), which also get generated based on the number of objects in the `choicesA` array.

I tried everything, I just can't figure it out. I can explain more if it's a bit unclear. Thank you a ton in advance.

**EDIT** : Thank you all for your great help, let me explain more :

I have a Spring REST API and two `Java` objects (JPA entities) named Resource & Action, the object Resource contains a List of Actions, and Action contains a reference to a Resource.

When I load a page, I get an array of `Resource` objects that I already saved return from the database by an $http.get() method,named `choicesA`, the structure of array is like this :

```
[
{"idResource":1, "nameResource": "resName1"},
{"idResource":2, "nameResource": "resName2"}
......etc depends oh how much rows I got from the DB
]
```

I have another method, $http.post() which posts an array of `Action` objects named `choicesB` a seperate non nested array. The array structure is like this :

```
[
{"idAction":1, "nameAction":"nameAction1", "resource": 
   {"idResource":1, "nameResource": "resName1"},
{"idAction":2, "nameAction":"nameAction2", "resource": 
   {"idResource":2, "nameResource": "resName2"},
   ..
}
{...},
{...}
...
]
```

So the `choicesA` array contains the `Resource` objects that I got with the $http.get(), then I want to fill `Action` objects in the `choicesB` array and then save the array using $http.post(), every `Action` should contain a `Resource` object. If I click to add more actions in the first `fieldset` tag for example, means that I want to fill the first `Action` object in `choicesB` array, and assign to it the first `Resource` object located in the `choicesA` array etc..

I want to be able to decide the number of actions and fill them out, then saving them to the `choicesB` array. but every action is related to a specific `Resource` object like I described.

I hope it's clear now, I'm sorry & Thank you again.

Comment: I'm updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko I wanted it in a different way but your example works as well, Thank you a million !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question. Maybe this will help solve your problem.

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73z8oehv/3/).

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choicesA = [{
    id: 'choice1',
    choicesB:[]
  }, {
    id: 'choice2',
    choicesB:[]
  }];


  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choicesA.length + 1;
    $scope.choicesA.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo,
      choicesB:[]
    });
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function(ind) {
    $scope.choicesA.splice(ind,1);
  };

  $scope.addNewChoiceB = function(choice) {
    var newItemNo = choice.choicesB.length + 1;
    choice.choicesB.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
    });
  };

  $scope.removeChoiceB = function(choice,ind) {
    choice.choicesB.splice(ind,1);
  };

});
```

```css
fieldset {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}

.addfields {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#choicesDisplay {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(227, 250, 227);
  border: 1px solid rgb(171, 239, 171);
  color: rgb(9, 56, 9);
}

.remove {
  background: #C76868;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add choice</button>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choicesA">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
    <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">-</button>
    <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoiceB(choice)">Add fields</button>
    <div data-ng-repeat="choiceb in choice.choicesB">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choiceb.name" name="" placeholder="Enter field">
      <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoiceB(choice,$index)">-</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <div id="choicesDisplay">
    <pre>choicesA = {{ choicesA }}</pre>
    <pre data-ng-repeat="choiceb in choicesA">choicesB = {{ choiceb.choicesB }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/2p05uw5j/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I tried to edit your code to meet my needs but I failed. I edited my original post to describe more my case, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is have 2 nested arrays.

Then you would have nested `ng-repeat`. You keep track of which array by passing that array as argument of function

View

```
 <fieldset data-ng-repeat="group in choices">
    <div ng-repeat="choice in group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
      <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice(group)">Add fields</button>
      <button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice(group)">-</button>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

JS

```
$scope.choices = [
  // first group
  [{id: 'choice1'}, { id: 'choice2'}],
  //second group
  [{}]
];


$scope.addNewChoice = function(group) {
  var newItemNo = group.length + 1;
  group.push({
    'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
  });
};

$scope.removeChoice = function(group) {
  group.pop();
};
```

Note you will need to modify your `ID` system a bit. Normally this would come from server anyway

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnb32rm/287/)**</kbd>

Comment: @charlieftfl Thank you, your answer helped a lot and I'm sorry if it was unclear, I edited my original post to describe more my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<fieldset>
<input  data-ng-repeat="choice in choicesA" type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter name">
<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
<button class="remove" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
</fieldset>
```

First portion of your requirment is solved by this  that textbox is added to sepecific fieldset and 2nd requirment is unclear to me replace your htmlcode with this